# Pythagorean pentagons

Tags: mathematics, optimization, dissection

To follow up on the theme of so called "pythagorean" dissections, here is one more for you to chew on.  I hope you don't get bored.
[image]

The pentagons above have sides respectively 3, 4 and 5.
Pythagoras says that the sum of the areas of the first two equals the area of the last one. Yes, the Pythagorean theorem works with any shape, not only squares.

Your task is to dissect the first two pentagons in a finite number of pieces and reassemble them to form the third pentagon.  Of course, without gaps and without overlaps.
You can rotate and flip the pieces as you wish.

These dissection are proven to be always possible.  But it can take many pieces and be ugly.  So I am asking to minimize the number of pieces.  I know at least one elegant solution.  But I don't know whether it is optimal.

Just to avoid weird solutions, the pieces must be simple polygons.

Comment: Wow, I never realized that the Pythagorean theorem also works for other shapes than squares. Even circles!

Comment: I would express it as "Pythagoras says that the sum of the areas of the first two equals the area of the last one." For a planar figure, _surface_ would mean perimeter.

Comment: It is a better formulation.  I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Looks like I unintentionally made @Edward H delete their very cool 6-piece answer. Please consider undeleting it.

Comment: FYI, here is an example of a weird solution: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50097/dissecting-the-holey-octomino-into-a-square/77551#77551

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's another possible solution, without flipping:

> [image: dissection]

Comment: Beat you to it by two minutes, I'm afraid. Your shapes are cool, though.

Comment: It is one hour 2 minutes actually.  But it is still awesome.  I wish I could give 2 checkmarks.

Comment: @FlorianF I checked the timestamps and it appears that the difference is two minutes (and nine seconds).

Comment: Silly me!  I looked at the "answered time", not the "edited time".  So yes, 2 minutes it was.

Comment: Since the solutions are almost simultaneous, I decided to accept this one to give it more visibility.  Loopy has already plenty of upvotes.

Comment: @FlorianF loopy never has enough upvotes! I'm kidding, of course. This answer is very deserving.

Answer (score 34):

6 pieces, no flipping required:

> [image]

History:

7 pieces, no flipping required:

> [image]

8 pieces, requires two flips

> [image]

9 pieces, requires one flip

> [image]

very similar:

10 pieces, no flipping required

> [image]

not very elegant, though

Comment: Wow!  I managed to do 11.  It starts nicely with the large pieces but yeah, the small pieces get a bit messy.  But I said it is the count that counts.

Comment: The 8 piece solution is stunning! I never would've expected multiple concave pieces.

Comment: @isaacg Turns out at least the second non-convex piece was sub-optimal, see update.

Comment: @loopywalt Now a single doubly-concave piece rather than two singly-concave pieces, amazing!

Comment: Is this minimal? Clearly you need at least 5 pieces. Can it be done with 5 pieces? Or is there a better lower bound? And the rather irregular shape makes me wonder; what is the minimum number of edges/vertices for such a dissection?

Comment: Amazing!  And frankly, I don't know how you can come up with such shapes.

Comment: one way to try is using geogebra, at least, that was my attempt, but, without sufficient creativity, for me, no even remote, success (15 was my target), so yes: @loopywalt : do you use some software or only your splendid imagination?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName I use shapely to make the pictures. As for strategy I have found that it helps to work out the characteristic angles (mostly multiples of 36° and rarely 54°) and length units (1 and the golden ratio, phi). Besides that it is quite a bit of incremental work, quite literally moving bits around; you can see in my post the evolution from 10 to 7 pieces.

Comment: I just can't wait to see your 5 piece solution :-)

Comment: About your 6-piece solution.  Not only there is no flipping, but the rotation is minimal.  The small pentagon rotation is unavoidable.  The length of unmatched edges facing each direction is 3+4 = 7 in the first two pentagons.  But you need only 5.  Rotating the pentagon "negates" one unit on each face.  Turning it 180° makes each edge face the opposite direction and absorb another unit length.  That brings the total of unmatched edges to 5 unit per side.  I hope you follow my explanations.

Comment: @FlorianF that's a nice way of looking at it, I wonder if this angle could be used to prove that 6 is minimal (if it is minimal).

Comment: @Servaes I think one can use a cleverly sliced 4-unit pentagon to cover two corners of the 5-unit pentagon, so it isn't clear to me why we would need five pieces. My best bound is three pieces.

Answer (score 32):

My efforts to minimize the number of pieces did not improve upon loopy walt's best, but here is another 7-piece solution without flipping:

> [image]

Sixteen pieces, with some flipping required.

> [image]

Comment: Nice!  A different approach than mine.  But let's see if someone finds a better solution ;-).

Comment: I'm curious - can this method be extended to any regular polygon? It looks like it probably should work for them but I'm not convinced...

Comment: It may not be minimal, but the symmetry is quite pleasing to the eye :)

Comment: I believe it works for every regular polygon.  So I probably won't post a "pythagorean heptagons" puzzle :-).

Comment: I can't upvote a second time, but hats off for the seven pieces!

Comment: Amazing ... can you perhaps also mention what tools (apart of your brain) you use to find such solution, ... Seems in any case that a full smaller version is a way to go.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName https://www.geogebra.org/geometry

Comment: @FlorianF There is a simple five piece solution for hexagons, but heptagons are not so trivial. My first solution here provides a 22 piece solution for heptagons. Not very impressive.

Answer (score 24):

OK, I'll give you my solution for reference.

> [image]
>
>   Elegant, imho, but with 11 pieces not quite optimal.

And just for fun, here is another seven piece solution.

> [image]

And finally my own 6-piece solution

> [image]
>
>  It looks so broken.  Just don't ask how I came up with it!

Comment: +1 Very elegant!

Comment: Wow! And you are asking me how I came up with mine?! Btw. if you rotate the top two small pieces in the large pentagon (funny how these two appear in your, Daniel's and my solution) then five out of the seven pieces need translation only, no flipping no rotation. Also, the rotation required of the remaining two can be made 180°.

Comment: Yeah, in the meantime I learned how it is done...  I actually made it intentionally more convoluted than necessary.  The two top pieces, I turned them like this for esthetic reasons.  Btw Daniel's and mine are actually related, you can transform mine into his using simple steps.  So there are similarities.

Comment: I keep coming back to this question, and am impressed anew each time.

Comment: Looking at it again, it appears my last 6-piece solution is a variation of loopy's.  Both solutions can be dissected into the same 9 pieces.